# Where is XMLHttpRequest.responseStream defined?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, reference

Take a look at the `graphics` part of the [GoogleAPI reference](http://code.google.com/apis/desktop/docs/gadget_apiref.html#framework.graphics). It says that `loadImage` takes either a `string`, or the `responseStream` property of an `XMLHttp`. By `XMLHttp`, I assume it means `XMLHttpRequest`.

My problem is that I can't find documentation for this **field** (the `responseStream` field) anywhere. I've had no luck googling it (ironc), it's not in "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide"... yet these gadgets that use it seem to work.

[This post](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1774868&SiteID=1) says that responseStream seems to not be accessible from a browser's XMLHttpRequest. From whose is it, then? Is it just a Google Desktop thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all, IIRC it was originally developed by Microsoft and has been part of IE since v5.0 (not sure about other browsers).

See the [XMLHttpRequest at W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) or [Google answer](http://code.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=79663&topic=11366).

**EDIT**: Finally found the article I was reading: [MSDN > MSXML 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760305(VS.85).aspx)

> **responseStream**
>
> If you are requesting
>   binary data, then the responseStream
>   attribute contains the response data
>   in a binary stream.

Comment: er, I know that XMLHttpRequest is defined well, I meant the .responseStream property in particular =P.

Comment: for example, the reference you linked doesn't mention responseStream anywhere.

Comment: sorry, didn't clarify it enough.
responseStream / responseBody - is not a part of the standard and has been proposed for future versions.